# Error while executing a function

Tags: matlab

I get this error:

```
Undefined function or variable "a".  
Error in image_filtering (line 55)  
a(end+1) = peaksnr ;  
Error in runtime_test (line 15)  
[out_img , a_out] = image_filtering (v (:,:),inpt_img);
```

what I intend to do is to pass a vector of seven elements (values 1 to 7) and an Image to a function to execute a series of filters, then calculate the psnr value of the output image and store the psnr value in an array and pass the output image and the psnr array back.

image_fintering code:

```
function [output_image,a] = image_filtering( filter_order,input_image )    
     se1 = strel('disk',1);        % disk, radius 1
     se2 = strel('disk',2);        % disk, radius 2
     se3 = strel('disk',4);        % disk, radius 4
     se4 = strel('line',5,45);     % line, length 5, angle 45 degrees
     se5 = strel('line',5,0);      % line, length 5, angle 0 degrees
     se6 = strel('square',3);      % 3-by-3 square
     se7 = strel('ball',15,5);
filter_iterations= size(filter_order);
filter_iterations = filter_iterations(2);
disp(filter_order);

for i = 1:filter_iterations

    switch filter_order(1,i)
        case 1 
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se1);
        case 2 
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se2);
        case 3 
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se3);
        case 4 
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se4);
        case 5 
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se5);
        case 6 
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se6);
        case 7
            output_image = imclose(input_image,se7);

    end


end

peaksnr = psnr(output_image,input_image);
a(end+1) = peaksnr ;
end
```

this is the calling code
runtime_test

```
 v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
    inpt_img = imread('A10001.png');
    [out_img , a_out] = image_filtering (v (:,:),inpt_img);
```

Comment: The error message is *very* clear: you've not defined/allocated the variable `a` before attempting to index into it. It even shows you the line of code involved. Have you tried to fix this?

Comment: add `a=[]` in the beggining of your code

Comment: I tried, I'm new to matlab and there is something that I don't get, how can I fill an array from the function and pass it back?  The array length and values should be defined in the function.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The will produce an "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." error. All that's needed is to change `a(end+1) = peaksnr ;` to `a = peaksnr;`.

Comment: the a = peaksnr assigns a single value to "a". what i intend to do is to call the function a number of times and to store the calculated psnr values in "a"

Comment: I was testing how to add a single element to an array

Comment: @horchler Will it? `a = []; a(end+1) = 27.824`? It's less efficient than preallocating the array, but it should still work.

Comment: @beaker: You're right. I didn't set it equal to anything for some reason so of course it gave an error. I knew I had done such things before so it was weird that I got an error. Too tired.

Comment: @horchler Been there, done that. Heck, I've done it *without* being tired. ;) But yes, that's something to look out for. If you *reference* the value of an array beyond its assigned size as an r-value, it will throw an error.